# Do we posses technology to rebuild sequenced DNA?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing

Is there existing technology that would allow to rebuild DNA molecule from a digital file storing sequenced DNA?

If not, does there at least exist theory explaining how such device could be built?

Comment: This question is quite broad. Also see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gene_synthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in fact synthesizing short stretches of DNA and RNA is available through [several commercial services](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/biology/standard-dna-synthesis.html). However this limited to tiny DNA fragments (say 120 base pairs or so). Longer sequences require custom laboratory work.

Comment: Making long sequences is possible too. [The J. Craig Venter instistute synthesized an entire bacterial genome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_laboratorium).

Comment: @user137 While it's true that long sequences can be made, this most often requires 'manual' stitching of several smaller fragments. However, current technology can already generate fragments of a few 1000bp (see e.g. [here](https://eu.idtdna.com/pages/products/genes-and-gene-fragments/gblocks-gene-fragments))

Comment: Thousands of base pairs is trivially possible with current technology - it's an off-the-shelf order from many companies. Tens of thousands becomes tricky. More importantly, although the question doesn't specifically ask this, this could not be used to re-create extinct animals (other than *perhaps* bacteria) because among other things epigenetic information would be missing.